# Sum of number of partitons of $k$ into distinct parts as $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$ is less than $n$th power of $2$.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs

Prove, with a direct combinatorial argument,that for all positive integers $n$, we have $q(1)+q(2)+...+q(n) \leq 2^{n}$, where $q(n)$ denotes the number of partitons of n into distinct parts.

I have found this problem in the book 'Introduction to Enumerative and Analytic Combinatorics' by Miklos Bona. I am going nowhere with this problem. Can anyone please give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: Partition of $n$ into how many distinct parts because $P(n, k) $ denotes partition of $n$ objects into $k$ groups.

Comment: It can be any number of parts. Just that in the partition, no number should occur more than once. For example, 4 can be partitioned into 4+0 and 3+1. So 2 partitions with distinct parts.

Comment: I think you mean partition into 2 parts. Otherwise, you could partition 4 also into 3+1+0, I.e. three parts

Comment: No, I am sorry. 4 can be partitioned into 4 and 3+1. 0 will not come. Distinct numbers should be there except 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every partition of a number $k\le n$ into distinct parts corresponds uniquely to a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; the inequality follows since the number of such subsets is $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you. It is a beautiful solution.